# Xamarin Android [Application] annotation and static values

Tags: android, xamarin, static-members

I have a simple Android application that needs to save an authentication session object to communicate with a REST API when the app runs.

My impression was to make this session object available as a static object as part of my Android `Application` class and to initialise the session within this context:

```
[Application]
public class MyApp : Application
{
    static public Session session;

    public MyApp(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(handle,transfer)
    {
        // database is initialised here

        MyApp.session = new Session (database);
    }
}
```

This seems to work well until I discovered that when I tried to access the `MyApp.session` from within my `MainActivity` that `MyApp.session` was set to `null`.

I'm now using the `MainActivity` class `OnCreate` method to initialise the session and now the session seems to keep it value.

Is there something with the `Application` class and static variables I'm not aware off? I was assuming that the instance of `MyApp` would be available throughout the lifetime of the application.

Can I still use the Application class to initialise variables or is this best done in the `OnCreate` of the `MainActivity`?

Comment: Don't initialize it in constructor. Override OnCreate and do it there.

Comment: @StevanMladenovic I'm currently doing that. I'd like to understand why. The `MyApp` instance should be available for the life time of the application, so why initialize in the main activity?

Comment: You can (and actually should) write an OnCreate method inside **MyApp**.

Comment: Using the `MyApp::OnCreate` seems indeed to be working. Make it an answer (instead of a comment) and I will accept it as correct.